# Determine which timer just finished c#

Tags: c#, timer

I was wondering if there is a way to determine which timer just elapsed based on 'duration' or something else, because I create lots of individual timers all with different intervals or durations, by using 'sender' or 'e' without having to create multiple timers or elapsed event handlers.

Code:

```
    public void timePowerup(float duration)
    {
        Timer timedDelay = new Timer();
        timedDelay.Interval = duration;
        timedDelay.AutoReset = false;
        timedDelay.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timedDelayElapsed);
        timedDelay.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void timedDelayElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: If you want to react to different timers in different ways, why on earth are you using the same `Elapsed` handler for them? Are you in some weird environment where you have to pay money for each function you create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `sender`. It is the timer which triggered the current event. Try

```
public void timedDelayElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer)sender;
}
```

From [Events, Delegates, and CLR Event System Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833085.aspx):

> By convention, event delegates in the .NET Framework have two parameters, the source that raised the event, represented by the *sender* parameter, and the data for the event, represented by the *e* parameter.